# I cannot compile using template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I compiled the following cords with g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class Node<const char*>{
private:
  string x_;
  Node* next_;
public:
  Node (const char* k, Node* next):next_(next),x_(k){}
  string data(){return x_;}
  Node *get_next(){return next_;}
};

$ g++ -c node01.cc
node01.cc:5: error: ‘Node’ is not a template
```

What's wrong?
I'm begginer for c++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up declarations and instantiations.  When you declare a template, you don't specify a type immediately after its name.  Instead, declare it like this:

```
template<class T>
class Node {
private:
  const T x_;
  Node *next_;
public:
  Node (const T& k, Node *next) : x_(k), next_(next) { }
  const T& data(){return x_;}
  Node *get_next(){return next_;}
};
```

Your original declaration also confuses `string`, `const char *`, and generic types that should be in terms of `T`.  For a template like this, you probably want to let the user define the type of the member (`x_`).  If you explicitly declare it as `const char *` or `string`, you're losing genericity by limiting what the user can use for `T`.

Notice that I changed the types of the instance variables, the parameters of the constructor and the return type of `data()` to be in terms of `T`, too.

When you actually instantiate a variable of the template type, you can provide a concrete type parameter, *e.g.*:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    Node<char*> *tail = new Node<char*>("tail", NULL);
    Node<char*> *node = new Node<char*>("node", tail);
    // do stuff to mynode and mytail
}
```

Whenever you write the template name `Node` outside the template declaration, it's not complete until you provide a value for the parameter `T`.  If you just say `Node`, the compiler won't know what *kind* of node you wanted.

The above is a little verbose, so you might also simplify it with a typedef when you actually use it:

```
typedef Node<char*> StringNode;
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    StringNode *tail = new StringNode("tail", NULL);
    StringNode *node = new StringNode("node", tail);
    // do stuff to mynode and mytail
}
```

Now you've built a linked list of two nodes.  You can print out all the values in the list with something like this:

```
for (StringNode *n = node; n; n = n->get_next()) {
    cout << n->data() << endl;
}
```

If all goes well, this will print out:

```
node
tail
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class declaration should look like this:

```
template<class T>
class Node{
private:
  T x_;
  Node* next_;
public:
  Node (const T& k, Node* next):next_(next),x_(k){}
  T data(){return x_;}
  Node *get_next(){return next_;}
};
```

Notice how I removed all references to `string` or `const char *` and replaced them with the generic type `T`. Your class, since it is templated, should not refer to any specific type but should do everything in terms of the generic `T` type.

The `const char *` is specified later when you declare a `Node` variable. Or it could be any other type, not just `const char *`. The point is, when you're declaring the `Node` class you just use the generic type `T` in the code without reference to any specific type. You specify a specific type only when you actually use a `Node`.

```
Node<const char *> stringNode("foo", NULL);
Node<int>          intNode(5, NULL);
```

This has allowed us to have a single definition of the `Node` class but be able to use it to create both nodes where the data is a string and nodes where the data is an integer. Hooray templating!